# MediaPlayer duplicates song after get back to application after pressing Back Button

Tags: android

This is how I initialize `MediaPlayer` in my application:

**e.g:**

```
public class MyClass extends AppCompatActivity {
    MediaPlayer mp;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.mysong);
      mp.start();
//...
```

When I minimize the application by pressing Back Button from my Android Device, so if I get back to the application the `MediaPlayer` duplicates the song and so on, the weird thing is that doesn't happen if I use Home Button instead, I can press Home Button, so the application minimizes and when I get back to the application, everything is fine, but if I do this way by pressing Back Button instead, so the problem happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you press Back button to minimize the application `onDetroy()` method of `Activity` is called and it destroys the Activity but your music remains created. After reopening the `Activity` it again calls `onCreate()` and your music is created again.

Now in the case of Home button `onPause()` and `onStop()` are called and your `Activity` does not get destroyed so if you open the app again `onCreate()` method does not get called and your music does not get duplicated.

You should call `mp.stop()` and `mp.release()` in `onDestry()` of `Activty` so that your music gets released before `Activity` destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

When you press back button your activity is destroyed (onDestroy() method is called) and removed from the memory by garbage collector. Since the media player is a property of the MyClass (activity) it will be removed by GC as well.

When you press home button the activity is not destroyed but stopped (onStop() method is called). The activity stays in memory that's why it works.

see [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)

If you want to make your media player live longer than the activity, you should create and start the media player inside a Service.
Check this tutorial [Using MediaPlayer in a service](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer#mpandservices)